# Remote URL (http) as icon for AppBarCommand in WinJS Universal App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs, win-universal-app

First off, this is a Universal App and this specifically is happening when it is run on a Windows Phone.

I am creating an AppBarCommand in my app via JavaScript.  Here is the code:

```
var commandElement = document.createElement('button');
var command = new WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand(commandElement, {
    id: [id],
    label: [text],
    onclick: function () {  }
});
```

If I try to set the 'icon' property with a remote URL (http://)  it does not work.  Is this not possible on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some code like yours in a Win 8.1 app that did not work at all when I used the same code in WinPhone 8.1 app.

I had to change my code declare the AppBar in my html with every possible command and show or hide commands depending on that page needs.

Comment: Sadly this is the answer.  I spoke with Microsoft and this is by design, at least for now.

Answer (score -1):

create custom class then use app bar

```
public static void AddNewAppBarinPage(Page myPage)
    {
        CommandBar cbar = new CommandBar { ClosedDisplayMode = AppBarClosedDisplayMode.Compact };


        AppBarButton playBar = new AppBarButton { Label = "in play", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Shop) };
        cbar.PrimaryCommands.Add(playBar);
        playBar.Click -= playBar_Click;
        playBar.Click += playBar_Click;

        AppBarButton audioBar = new AppBarButton { Label = "my audio", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Audio) };
        cbar.PrimaryCommands.Add(audioBar);
        audioBar.Click -= audioBar_Click;
        audioBar.Click += audioBar_Click;

        AppBarButton settingBar = new AppBarButton { Label = "settings", Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Setting) };
        cbar.PrimaryCommands.Add(settingBar);
        settingBar.Click -= settingBar_Click;
        settingBar.Click +=settingBar_Click;

        AppBarButton switchToSoccer = new AppBarButton { Label = "switch to soccer" };
        cbar.SecondaryCommands.Add(switchToSoccer);
        switchToSoccer.Click -= switchToSoccer_Click;
        switchToSoccer.Click += switchToSoccer_Click;

        myPage.BottomAppBar = cbar;
       // rootFrame = myPage.Frame;

    }
```

Comment: The question is specifically for JavaScript (WinJS)